# Image Processing: Laplacian of Gaussian with 2 thresholds

Tags: image-processing, filter, convolution, gaussian

I am currently taking course in image processing, and for the final project we need to use Laplacian of Gaussian edge detector using 2 thresholds, and I have problem figuring what the threshold should be.

From what I read online I need to find the zero crossing places where the image after the filteration equals to zero and these are pixels that might be an edge.

For the threshold I read here https://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~elec539/Projects97/morphjrks/laplacian.html 
that I need to calculate the local variance and compare it to the threshold, but I couldn't find some more information about how to calculate this threshold.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should pick the thresholds. They're parameters to the algorithm that you can adjust until the output is to your liking.

Comment: Thank you got yout comment. I would like to know how to at least calculate the minimal threshold...